# Whats wrong with this code? replace method

Tags: python

Im new to python and im working on some challenges to try and improve my skills. Im stuck at this challenge though it seems fairly easy. I get an "end statement expected" error and im not sure why im sure this is a very easy question but im stuck nonetheless lol.

```
t = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp." \
       " bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. " \
       "sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."

def decoder(text):
    for i in text:
        if i == "k":
            text.replace(i, "m")
        elif i == "o":
            text.replace(i, "q")
        elif i == "e":
            text.replace(i, "g")
    return text

print decoder(t)
```

Comment: Note that `str.replace` does not work in-place because strings are immutable.  You need to do: `text = text.replace(i, "m")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in other answers, strings are immutable. So `text.replace()` will not have any effect. And the `replace()` method of string will replace all occurrences of the old by new, so there is no need to use `for`-loop if you use `replace()` method. But if you want to do it in a loop, you can construct the string by adding characters of `t` like this,

```
def decoder(text):
    decoded = ""
    for i in text:
        if i == "k":
            decoded += "m"
        elif i == "o":
            decoded += "q"
        elif i == "e":
            decoded += "g"
        else:
            decoded += i
    return decoded
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable in Python. `replace` return a new string, with characters replaced.

What is the purpose of the for-loop? `replace` does nothing, if the character is not in the string.

Comment: looking back over my script after reading through some of these answers I can see how silly using a for loop with the replace method is. Again im still learning lol

Answer (score 0):

```
t = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp." \
       " bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. " \
       "sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."

def decoder(text):
    text = text.replace('k', "m")
    text = text.replace('o', "q")
    text = text.replace('e', "g")
    return text

print decoder(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to loop on a character basis. You can simply run `print t.replace("k", "m").replace("o", "q").replace("e", "g")` which will try to replace for every character in the string.